# Mysql query is not working but i could not guess why

Tags: mysql

Hello Friends I have two tables one is `customer` and the other one is `new_party_estimate`. But My following query is not working. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
SELECT 
  acc_name,
  customer_id 
FROM
  customers 
WHERE STATUS = 'e' 
AND acc_name NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    customer 
  FROM
    new_party_estimate 
  WHERE closed = '0' 
  AND (
    customer_alt = '' 
    OR customer_alt IS NULL
  )
) 
ORDER BY acc_name
```

I am running the sub query separately and it is giving the output. But When i run the full query at once the mysql shows empty result. Please tell what would be the problem!

Table `Customers` is Following with few records.

```
acc_name                      customer_id
CAMPUS FASHION_khyati         CAM-11
PAPPU SUIT HOUSE              PAPAAR5
R K FASHION                   R KAAR6
SELECTION MENS WEAR           SELAAR7
```

Table `new_party_estimate` is Following with few records.

```
    customer
    LOVELY DRESSES
    ASHIRWAD GARMENTS
    AKASH DEEP
    ABDUL LATIF READYMADE SALE
```

Comment: You have mentioned one table is `customer` but in your sql it is `from customers`

Comment: Query looks good. Give us some examples of rows (with all fields) which must be retrieved

Comment: Dear djidi i must get all the records of customers table in the result as they are not in new_party_estimate.

Comment: @SomeshGaur You have to give more informations about tables : what are fields in **`new_party_estimate`** ? You show only `customer` in this table and not others fields mentioned in query like `customer_alt` or `closed`. And show rows matching in **`Customers`** and in **`new_party_estimate`** to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing obvious in you query, although IN can be inefficient (using EXISTS would be more efficient).

Another alternative would be to do a LEFT JOIN but only bring back records where there is no match:-

```
SELECT acc_name,
        customer_id 
FROM customers 
LEFT OUTER JOIN new_party_estimate
ON customers.acc_name = new_party_estimate.customer
AND closed = '0' 
AND (customer_alt = '' 
OR customer_alt IS NULL)
WHERE new_party_estimate.customer IS NULL
AND STATUS = 'e' 
ORDER BY acc_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer of this question but i am not sure why it is happening.

While running this query if there is any row in new_party_estimate table having all values equal to null then this query does not work.